# OpenCV on OSX - how to use a secondary camera rather than the default one

Tags: macos, opencv, camera, webcam

In my processing code, I use 
`opencv.loadImage(video)`
to load the image from the video source.

This works well for the default camera on the MacBook Air.

But I would like to use a USB camera. In PhotoBooth I can switch camera. What is the OpenCV command to direct the source to a different camera?

Alternatively, is there a MacBook setting where I could default the camera to the one on USB port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to open a camera you can use VideoCapture. The C++ Definition is below:

```
VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int device)
```

By changing the number of `device` you can select the different cameras registered by your operating system. generally the default (built in) camera is `0` and any additional cameras will be numbered after.

A small example on how to open cameras with VideoCapture is below.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        imshow("Video", frame);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, the "default" camera on my mac was the usb camera. Also to compile this assuming you have use homebrew to install g++ and opencv2, use ` g++ open-camera.cpp -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui`